# USQL Unit testing with ADL tools for VS 2017 - Error after upgrading to 2.3.4000.x

Tags: testing, azure-data-lake, u-sql

One of the team member after upgrading the ADL tools for VS to version 2.3.4000.x, getting the  below error..

> Error : (-1,-1) 'E_CSC_SYSTEM_INTERNAL: Internal error!
>
> The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups.
>
> This usually indicates a problem in the Formatter.'
> Compile failed!

Tried to downgrade back to version ( 2.3.3000.2 ), it didn't help much.

If encountered similar issue, found the reason and resolved it, please share it.

Comment: At least two of our team members are also getting this. Version 2.3.3000.5 here.

Comment: Also faced another issue. When we submit a job (just ‘select’ from a table to .csv file) from visual studio, we got empty result set. But when we ran same script from PowerShell or Test, able to  get the result. It helped us to understand the versions are causing issues and we thought cleaning up datarootpath might help.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

After trying out few unsuccessful options, decided to clean up the files in USQLDataRoot including localrunmetadata and *catalog* folder. Still, when I submit a job to create a database, there was no error, but it didn’t create the database.

We had some powershell scripts to setup the database and other objects. Ran the powershell script, which created the database and procedures.  Then we were able to run the tests successfully. One more thing to double check, make sure build platform is set to “x64”.

Comment: Deleting the contents of C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\USQLDataRoot also did the trick for me. I'm now able to build. 