# Unable to run U-SQL script locally in visual studio

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-analytics

When i run the u-sql script locally in visual studio.. it is throwing error
`E_CSC_SYSTEM_INTERNAL: Internal error! The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups. This usually indicates a problem in the Formatter.`

```cs
@input =
    EXTRACT         
            Address_1 string,
            Address_2 string
            FROM "/Data_new"
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '~', quoting : false, silent : true);
@output2 =
    SELECT DISTINCT 
                    Address_1,
                    Address_2
FROM @input;
OUTPUT @output2
TO "/out.txt"
USING Outputters.Text(delimiter : '~' , quoting : false);
```

Comment: Hi @steve checkout similar SO thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181503/usql-unit-testing-with-adl-tools-for-vs-2017-error-after-upgrading-to-2-3-4000) which addressing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Important things to note before you run U-SQL script locally in visual studio.

- U-SQL SDK only support x64 environment, make sure to set build platform target as x64 and set your test environment as x64​.
- Make sure to copy all dependency files (correct versions) as part of your solution.
- Do not change default data root path.
- Before running any USQL script from test, make sure it runs successfully.  Exclude any audit columns like UpdatedTime, ProcessedOn, etc from data comparison.

For more details, refer "[ADLA - Run U-SQL script on your local machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-local-run)" and "[ADLA - U-SQL](http://obulis.blogspot.com/)".

Hope this helps.